# Use of & in Footnote editing

Tags: editing, footnotes

If the intent is to reduce the # of characters in footnotes/endnotes (using the Chicago/Turabian style), would it be proper to replace "and" with "&"? For example, "ed. & trans," pages "4, 7, & 19," etc.

Comment: Hi Dennis, and welcome to ELU!  Unfortunately, questions regarding formatting style are generally off-topic here; you may want to check on writers.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: Many times the intent is to make footnotes as compact as possible, so using ampersand instead of "and" is consistent.  It depends on the style chosen for the book/article.

Comment: @Hellion thanks for the reference to writers.stackexchange.com. I will look there first next time.

Comment: @Hot Licks, thanks. It is reassuring, however, unless the editor forces me to reduce characters even more, I will not use the "&" since I don't see it used often in my field.

Comment: The official style guide, whichever it is, will yell you if this is allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be worth seeking guidance on this from your publisher/tutor/supervisor.  As far as I can determine, general advice in the [Chicago Manual of Style Citation Guide](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/tools_citationguide.html) does not strictly legislate for your first question.  That said, such systems are frequently tweaked by particular institutions and local preferences will *always* supersede the more general scheme.

I am much more experienced in MHRA (which also uses footnotes) than Chicago/Turabian, and my own personally tweaked version of [MHRA style](http://www.mhra.org.uk/Publications/Books/StyleGuide/StyleGuideV3_2.pdf) would be fine with **your first example** in principle, but with two reservations:  first, terminate ‘trans.’ with a point, because it is just as much an abbreviation as ‘ed.’, for ‘ed. & trans.’; and also, if I found myself *this stuck* to save characters I would start wondering about some broader way to make the writing more economical, rather than shaving characters out of footnotes.

**Your second example** pages ‘4, 7, & 19,’ might not be an issue.  You seem to have picked up that ‘pages’, ‘p.’ and ‘pp.’ are usually unnecessary in Chicago/Turabian (except occasionally, for clarity in a spectacularly complex citation).  In other style schemes with which I am familiar, the numerical notation here would just be ‘4, 7, 19’ with no ‘and’ or ‘&’ at all.  I can’t find anything in the Chicago Manual to oppose this.

In the end, though, *all of this could be trumped* by the vagaries and details of some preferred local policy.  I think that the above gives a fair idea of what to expect if you *have* to decide on this for yourself, in the dark, but seeking specifically knowledgeable input on the ground would be the thing.

Comment: Captain Cranium, thanks for such an answer. The un-terminated "trans" was an error. I think your advice on finding other ways to reduce characters (other than shaving them out of footnotes) is appropriate. I don't see much use for "&" in my field, so, I think I will not use it either.

Comment: I think that that is wise. I didn't want to make an upfront big deal of personal advice, but I agree with what you say here. I suspect that adopting this kind of '&' policy with footnotes might make you look more desperate than anything else. When I was at school, I _briefly_ flirted similarly with _hyphenating_ things! As I say, if you are in this kind of trouble for space then stepping back for a day or two and reappraising your overall writing/style/whatever policy is likely to pay bigger and better dividends–both now, and growing into the future–than scrabbling to save the odd character.